# Parallel promise return in order

Tags: promise, bluebird

I'm looking for an efficient way in Bluebird (or native Promise if necessary) to run a parallel array of promises and return them in order as they are completed. Almost like a queue lock, I guess?

So if I have an array of 5 functions, function 1 could take 150ms, function 2 could take 50ms, function 3 could take 50ms etc. All 5 functions are called in parallel but the callbacks returning values would only respond in the order I specify. Ideally something like this:

```
Promise.parallelLock([
    fn1(),
    fn2(),
    fn3(),
    fn4(),
    fn5()
])
.on('ready', (index, result) => {
    console.log(index, result);
})
.then(() => {
    console.log('Processed all');
})
.catch(() => {
    console.warn('Oops error!')
});
```

I think I can accomplish this with Bluebird coroutines? Just having trouble deciding structure that makes most sense/is most aligned with my above example.

Answer (score 3):

That's just `Promise.all` which just waits for all promises, a promise is like a value - if you have a promise the action was already performed:

```
Promise.all([
    fn1(),
    fn1(),
    fn1(),
    fn1(),
    fn1(),
    fn1(),
    fn1()
])
.then(results => {
    // this is an array of values, can process them in-order here
    console.log('Processed all');
})
.catch(() => {
    console.warn('Oops error!')
});
```

If you need to know when one is done, you can `.tap` (a `then` which doesn't change the return value)`them through`.map`before passing them to`.all`:

```
Promise.all([
    fn1(),
    fn1(),
    fn1(),
    fn1(),
    fn1(),
    fn1(),
    fn1()
].map((x, i) => x.tap(v => console.log("Processed", v, i))
.then(results => {
    // this is an array of values, can process them in-order here
    console.log('Processed all');
})
.catch(() => {
    console.warn('Oops error!')
});
```

Comment: Hmmm, so .tap() will only execute in the sequence that I specified? So if fn5() finishes first it will wait until fn1-4 are complete hence maintaining my sequence? If so...nice, that was easy :-p

Comment: `tap` won't, if you want it to sequence like that you can `.each` the `.taps`s instead of `.map` them. `Promise.each([fn1(), ....], x => x.tap(...))` (with bluebird, or with `.reduce` in other promise libraries.

Comment: That doesn't really net me the result I'm hoping for?